# Finding $\lim\limits_{ε→0}(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A+ε\mathbf I) ^{-1} \mathbf A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

I am given a problem to find$$\lim_{ε→0}(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A+ε\mathbf I)^{-1}\mathbf A^T.$$
It is fairly obvious that it reduces to $(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A)^{-1}\mathbf A^T$, but I am not sure I can say anything meaningful beyond that. I tried plugging in some values to MATLAB, just to see if I can notice a pattern, but other than returning some "close to singular" errors when I take the inverse of a matrix, I do not see anything that stands out.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: Are you familiar with Singular Value Decomposition?

Comment: You can compute the inverse explicitly from the SVD, which is exactly what showed up in the answer to your previous question. The largest singular value is then 1/eps and this blows up

Comment: I know you can compute the inverse explicitly, but the problem is in an abstract form. I'm asked to find the limit of the expression, which reduces to $\textbf{A}^H\textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^T$. I am not sure where to go from here - I'm assuming this expression reduces further to something obvious but am not sure what that is.

Comment: $A^TA$ is not necessarily invertible. The expression in question is a well-known limit expression for the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I have it.

We have

$\lim\limits_{ε→0}(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A+ε\mathbf I)^{-1} \mathbf A^T$

Which reduces to

$(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^T$

Under SVD, this becomes

$(\textbf{V} \Sigma^{2} \textbf{V}^{T})^{-1}\textbf{A}^{T}$

$(\textbf{V}\Sigma^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{V}^T)\textbf{A}^T$

$(\textbf{V}\Sigma^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{V}^T)\textbf{V}\Sigma\textbf{U}^T$

$\textbf{V}\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{U}^T$

$= (\textbf{A}^T){^{-1}}$

Comment: Your reduction does not make sense unless $A^TA$ is invertible.

Comment: Sorry, it was shown in a previous part that $(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A+ε\mathbf I)$ is invertible, and my "reduction" (though not strictly true) hold in the limit -- since the $- \epsilon \textbf{I}$ part vanishes in the limit, $(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A)$ is infinitesimally close to $(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A+ε\mathbf I)$ while still being invertible. I just leave off the epsilons since, in the limit, they make no contribution.

Comment: It sounds like you removed $\varepsilon$ after some steps because removing it does not matter. I want to say, it does matter. We even do not know $A$ is a square matrix so the inverse could exist.

Comment: $\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}$ is always a square matrix, is it not?

Comment: It is right, but you finally concludes the result of your reduction is $(A^T)^{-1}$.

Comment: Can you explain to me why this is a problem or which steps are wrong? the reduction to $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^T$ is wrong but irrelevant (just remember $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A})$ actually means $(\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^T$ with no zero eigenvalues (because of the epsilonI added), so an invertible matrix. From there it's just SVD across the board, and cancelling out where you can. (A^T)^-1 is just what I happened to get when I reduced the big SVD mess, but please tell me where I made a misstep!

Comment: Could you explain why $A^TA$ *actually means* $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ with no zero eigenvalues? I did not grasp the meaning of *actual meaning* in your comment.

Comment: Moreover, I think you repeatedly say we can evaluate the inverse of $A^TA$ since we add some $\varepsilon I$ so we can make it invertible. Imagine applying the same argument to justify "$0$ is invertible since $0+\varepsilon$ is invertible."

Comment: I have just said your evaluation is wrong because assumptions you have used is not applicable to general cases. I did not check the full detail of your proof, but I have a doubt that you can easily conclude $V^TV$ is the identity matrix. (I think it could have zeros in its diagonal entries.)

Comment: I'm not trying to say that $\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A}$ itself is invertible. The question is about the limit $\lim\limits_{ε→0}(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A+ε\mathbf I) ^{-1} \mathbf A^T$, which in this case is easier for me to think of as "$(\mathbf A^T\mathbf A) ^{-1} \mathbf A^T$ assuming we know $\mathbf A^T\mathbf A$ is invertible". We don't know ATA is invertible, but we know $\mathbf A^T\mathbf A+ε\mathbf I$ is invertible, and in the limit, the epsilon vanishes. I apologize for the confusion -- the reduction is a heuristic that, although not technically true, makes conceptualization clearer for me

Comment: In any event, the solution was released. The limit was $A^+$, the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. My mistake was inverting $\Sigma$ instead of inverting (taking the reciprocal of) the ENTRIES of $\Sigma$. So it's $\textbf{V}\begin{bmatrix}
1/\sigma_1 & 0 &  & \dots&  & 0\\ 
0 & \ddots &  &  &  & \\  
 &  & 1/\sigma_r &  &  & \\ 
\vdots &  &  & 0 &  & \vdots\\ 
 &  &  &  & \ddots  & \\ 
0 &  &\dots  &  &  & 0
\end{bmatrix}\textbf{U}^T$ instead of $\textbf{V}\Sigma^{-1}\textbf{U}^T$